# Talking between .NET and Node.JS via socket library

Tags: asp.net, .net, node.js, sockets, communication

The [NsSocket](https://github.com/nodejitsu/nssocket) library provides an easy way for one Node.JS app to talk to another Node.JS app over a socket. [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) is built for Node.JS to talk to a web frontend.  [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) is built to talk between an ASP.NET server and web frontend, as well as a variety of other clients.

I have a relatively large project written in Node.JS.  It currently uses the NsSocket interface for communicating with clients.  I would like to build a .NET client that can communicate this Node.JS server.  In other words, .NET needs to be able to pass messages back and forth over a socket to Node.JS.

What I'm therefore looking for is **a socket library that provides seamless communication between a Node.JS server and a .NET client**.

For my particular use case, the client and server would be running in the same computer cluster, so the network connection between the client and the server is very reliable.

I've been searching the web for about half an hour but haven't landed on anything promising.  Has anyone faced this problem before?  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.